# Twitter widget on Angular 2

Tags: javascript, angular, angular2-routing, twitter-widget

I created a Twitter widget and I'm trying to put it in my Angular 2 project, but the JS file does not work.

If I insert it with JS ([Here](http://www.sascha.tech/2016/10/08/angular2-using-the-twitter-javascript-widgets/)) it works, but when I switch to another tab and back (I have Angular Routing installed) it disappears and shows whatever is in A tag (so, "Tweets by ...").

HTML code (it's in home component):

```
<md-card-content>
  <a class="twitter-timeline" data-lang="en" data-height="350" data-theme="light" data-chrome="noborders nofooter noheader noscrollbar transparent" href="https://twitter.com/profile">Tweets by profile</a>
</md-card-content>
```

Script in home.component.ts, the code was provided by @Arg0n (look in answers section):

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Router, NavigationEnd } from '@angular/router';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-home',
  templateUrl: './home.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./home.component.css']
})
export class HomeComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(private _router : Router) { }

  public ngOnInit() {
    this._router.events.subscribe(val => {
      if (val instanceof NavigationEnd) {
        (<any>window).twttr = (function (d, s, id) {
            let js: any, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0],
                t = (<any>window).twttr || {};
            if (d.getElementById(id)) return t;
            js = d.createElement(s);
            js.id = id;
            js.src = "https://platform.twitter.com/widgets.js";
            fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);

            t._e = [];
            t.ready = function (f: any) {
                t._e.push(f);
            };

            return t;
        }(document, "script", "twitter-wjs"));
        twttr.widgets.load();
      }
    })
  }

}
```

**EDIT:**
Alright, I did some research and found out that I have to load the widget again with `twttr.widgets.load();` but doing that, it throws me an error.

I edited the code above, so you can see what I've tried. The code above returns an error:

`[ts] Cannot find name 'twttr'`

if I append (window). to it, it throws me this:

`EXCEPTION: Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: Cannot read property 'load' of undefined`

The documentation on load property is here: https://dev.twitter.com/web/javascript/initialization

Comment: You should provide more informations, how are we suppose to know how to solve your problem, if we don't know the code?

Comment: Done, anything else you need?

Comment: The script inserted by twitter probably doesn't run when you switch views in angular. Try using a router event to kick it off again.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Alright, I found a solution to this. When we switch between Angular routers, the widget unloads. That's why we put a subscriber, so we load the widget every time we switch between tabs. We can see [here](https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/twitter-for-websites/javascript-api/guides/scripting-loading-and-initialization) how to load the widget for lazy-loading content. When the page is ready, we can use that function to load the widget. Don't forget to unsubscribe after the view is destroyed!

Code:

```
import { Component, OnDestroy } from '@angular/core';
import { Router, NavigationEnd } from '@angular/router';

@Component({ ... })

export class HomeComponent implements OnDestroy {
  private twitter: any;

  constructor(private _router: Router) {
    this.initTwitterWidget();
  }

  initTwitterWidget() {
    this.twitter = this._router.events.subscribe(val => {
      if (val instanceof NavigationEnd) {
        (<any>window).twttr = (function (d, s, id) {
          let js: any, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0],
              t = (<any>window).twttr || {};
          if (d.getElementById(id)) return t;
          js = d.createElement(s);
          js.id = id;
          js.src = "https://platform.twitter.com/widgets.js";
          fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);

          t._e = [];
          t.ready = function (f: any) {
              t._e.push(f);
          };

          return t;
        }(document, "script", "twitter-wjs"));

        if ((<any>window).twttr.ready())
          (<any>window).twttr.widgets.load();

      }
    });
  }

  ngOnDestroy() {
    this.twitter.unsubscribe();
  }
}
```

Comment: I found removing the Router \ NavigationEnd event listeners, and instead just using ngAfterViewInit worked a little better for me, as the NavigationEnd event doesn't fire when reloading the browser at the same path. Thanks for the solution though, helped me loads!

Answer (score 2):

Example for my comment (relevant parts):

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Router, NavigationEnd } from '@angular/router';

@Component({ ... })
export class MyComponent implements OnInit {
  constructor(private _router: Router) {}

  public ngOnInit() {
    this._router.events.subscribe(val => {
      if (val instanceof NavigationEnd) {
        (<any>window).twttr = (function (d, s, id) {
            let js: any, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0],
                t = (<any>window).twttr || {};
            if (d.getElementById(id)) return t;
            js = d.createElement(s);
            js.id = id;
            js.src = "https://platform.twitter.com/widgets.js";
            fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);

            t._e = [];
            t.ready = function (f: any) {
                t._e.push(f);
            };

            return t;
        }(document, "script", "twitter-wjs"));
      }
    });
  }
}
```

Comment: It doesn't work, it doesn't show tweets when I switch between pages.

Comment: Okay, this is just a 'maybe' answer to be honest. Can't test this. Do you get any errors in console? Can you debug and set a breakpoint to see what happens?

Comment: Well, I get this error:
https://syndication.twitter.com/i/jot/syndication?l=%7B%22_category_%22%3A%…w%22%2C%22page%22%3A%22timeline%22%2C%22action%22%3A%22impression%22%7D%7D Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 400 ()

but I'm not sure if it's because of your code.
I'm gonna debug now.

Comment: Okay, the script doesn't run when I switch tabs.

Comment: You never get inside the `this._router.events.subscribe(val => { ... });` function?

Comment: Only when I (re)load the whole page.

Comment: Then it sounds as if you're on the same route even when changing tabs. Maybe you have another event, or your own 'clickOnTab' event you can hook up to?

Comment: Well, what's weird is: it doesn't go past "val instanceof NavigationEnd", it triggers fine if I log something before that statement, but it logs it three times.

Comment: Then maybe you have another version than me. Try to see which event is the last of them (the third), and replace `NavigationEnd` with that.

Comment: Sorry, I tried to put the `console.log` right after the instanceof statement and it works (it even triggers multiple times), but it won't go past `if (d.getElementById(id)) return t;`, so I guess that's intended, but it's still not working.

Comment: Try changing that line to: `if (d.getElementById(id)) d.getElementById(id).remove();`. If that gets you nowhere i'm at a loss without having any code/fiddle to look at.

Answer (score 1):

This will work for me on angular 7.2.2 and ionic 4.1. angular can build and ionic can build app and test on cordova.

solution from : [embedded Twitter widget on Angular 2+ app only shows up on the first page load](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47176195/embedded-twitter-widget-on-angular-2-app-only-shows-up-on-the-first-page-load)

```ts
import { Component, OnInit, OnDestroy, AfterViewInit, PLATFORM_ID, Inject } from '@angular/core';
import { isPlatformBrowser } from '@angular/common';

constructor(@Inject(PLATFORM_ID) private platformId: Object) {}

ngAfterViewInit() {
  if (isPlatformBrowser(this.platformId)) {
    setTimeout(function() {
      (<any>window).twttr = (function(d, s, id) {
        let js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0], t = (<any>window).twttr || {};

        if (d.getElementById(id)) return t;
        js = d.createElement(s);
        js.id = id;
        js.src = 'https://platform.twitter.com/widgets.js';
        fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
        t._e = [];
        t.ready = function(f) {
          t._e.push(f);
        };
        return t;
      }(document, 'script', 'twitter-wjs'));
      (<any>window).twttr.widgets.load();
    }, 100);
  }
}
```

put here in .ts and put twitter tag in template files