# Twitter Widget in an Angular 2 app.sss

Tags: angular, twitter-widget

I have embedded a Twitter feed widget (created from twitter page) in the homepage of an angular app. It works fine when the site is first loaded. However, when you navigate away from the homepage and then return, it disappears. It re-appears only when I refresh the page.

How can I make the twitter feed persist so I do not have to refresh the page to have it re-appear?

Answer (score 0):

This has been answered here. The last solution worked for me: [Twitter widget on Angular 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42993859/twitter-widget-on-angular-2)

One extra tip: make sure that you don't have the Twitter Widget script tag in your index.html.